# How can I clone a MobX observable? (edit save changes)

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a simple react form, and two observables in my MobX store:

```
@observable personalInfo = {
        email: '',
        gender: 1,
        birthDate: null, 
        location: ''
    };
@observable personalInfoInEdit = null;
```

When the form of the personal info is loaded (in the ctor) I am calling a method on my store:

```
reset_PersonalInfoInEdit() {
        this.personalInfoInEdit = observable(this.personalInfo);
}
```

What it dose is simply reseting the "in edit" object, filling it with data from the original data. If the user press "save changes" the "in edit" object will be copied to the original.

Is calling observable() with another observable is valid? Any side effects to this? (it seems to work)

And if not, are there are design patterns to elegantly handle this scenario of "in edit" object.

Comment: AFAIK, this is ok. But to make sure, cc @mweststrate

Comment: Can you not just do this.personalInfoInEdit = this.personalInfo

Answer (score 8):

The preferred pattern would be to use [createViewModel](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#createviewmodel) utility function from [mobx-utils](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils). So you would do:

```js
import { createViewModel } from 'mobx-utils'

reset_PersonalInfoInEdit() {
    this.personalInfoInEdit = createViewModel(this.personalInfo);
}
```

this has an added benefit of having some utility functions on the view model that allow you easily to reset to original data or submit them to original model:

```js
class Todo {
  \@observable title = "Test"
}

const model = new Todo()
const viewModel = createViewModel(model);

autorun(() => console.log(viewModel.model.title, ",", viewModel.title))
// prints "Test, Test"
model.title = "Get coffee"
// prints "Get coffee, Get coffee", viewModel just proxies to model
viewModel.title = "Get tea"
// prints "Get coffee, Get tea", viewModel's title is now dirty, and the local value will be printed
viewModel.submit()
// prints "Get tea, Get tea", changes submitted from the viewModel to the model, viewModel is proxying again
viewModel.title = "Get cookie"
// prints "Get tea, Get cookie" // viewModel has diverged again
viewModel.reset()
// prints "Get tea, Get tea", changes of the viewModel have been abandoned
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this existed. I wish it was in the main Mobx documentation.

Comment: Be aware! `createViewModel` is a neat trick, but it comes with some gotchas, including not being able to reference computed properties of the model.

Comment: What about nested properties, like `viewModel.list[i].name`? Is it possible to get a "recursive" viewmodel? Also, sometimes we really just want a clone.