# How can I make a MobX-backed form with undo that propagates changes immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185513/how-can-i-clone-a-mobx-observable-edit-save-changes), but with a caveat.

My model is a list of items, and a field called `selectedItem` that can either be null, or point to one of the items. This field is used by the editor component to render and edit.

I'd like to introduce the "cancel" functionality that rolls all changes back. I found `createViewModel`, and it looks great, but it implies that edits on the view-model won't propagate until I actually commit the changes. And if I do, I can't reset it back.

The thing is, I really like the fact that editing my model directly is immediately reflected in the main display (it's a calendar app, so the editor is next to the main calendar view). Is there any way to have this cake and eat it?

I also reimplemented the dirty field tracking manually, because I needed that for partial updates. The fact that `createViewModel` would track that for me would be a huge benefit, but I can't see how I could use it in solving my problem, save perhaps for removing the element I'm editing from the collection and rendering it separately... Anyway, if there's some "industry standard practice" to use here, it'd be great to know.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I ended up creating a temp variable to hold original data when `selectedItem` is set, and restore the data when clicking "cancel". Not an elegant solution but worked for me.